# git-clone fatal, permission denied

Tags: git, git-clone

I've got a new git that for some reason I can't clone on one machine.  Clone works fine from my laptop and various desktops, but from an older server with git --version 1.5.2.1 I get the following error:

```
git clone git@git.assembla.com:sbpy.git

Initialized empty Git repository in /home/pkp/test/sbpy/.git/
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fetch-pack from 'git@git.assembla.com:sbpy.git' failed.
```

I can't upgrade the local git.  Can anyone help me sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: You don't have the key on that machine.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to git.  how do i install the key?

Comment: This is not related to git, only to ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate ssh keys and link posted above is a good one.

To upload your public ssh key(s) (you can have multiple keys uploaded obviously, used on different computers maybe) to [assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home?affiliate=acroitor), go to: [Manage Ssh Keys](https://www.assembla.com/user/edit/edit_git_settings?affiliate=acroitor) tab on your user profile page.

Make sure you are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your repo. First you must configure your ssh keys.

Follow the https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys but don't copy keys to github.
Then add content of your public key (id_rsa.pub) to your account in assembla.com(I don't know the Assembla user interface, but there must by option to add your keys)

And then clone your repo.